# Adding js files from specific folder with webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a webpack configuration that is loading properly the .js files 
under config folder into vendor.js file as long as it is under  bower-components folder. But if  I moved the config folder out of bower-components and kept it under root folder called commission. Now the .js files under config folder are not loading into vendor.js. Not sure what is causing the issue. How to load all the js files from specific folder into vendor.js using webpack..Appreciate any help in resolving this.

Thanks

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var ngAnnotatePlugin = require('ng-annotate-webpack-plugin');
var StatsWriterPlugin = require("webpack-stats-plugin").StatsWriterPlugin;
var ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
var ChunkManifestPlugin = require('chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin');

var annotate = new ngAnnotatePlugin({
  add: true
});

var manifestPlugin = new ManifestPlugin();

var chunkManifest = new ChunkManifestPlugin({
  filename: "./manifest.json",
  manifestVariable: "webpackManifest"
});

var occurencePlugin = new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin();

var stats = new StatsWriterPlugin({
  filename: "./stats.json" //
});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./tmp/index.js"
  },
  cache: true,
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  output: {
    path: "./tmp",
    filename: "[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "/featuresets/[name]/[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|server|test|vendor|dist)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          optional: ['runtime'],
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [annotate,stats,manifestPlugin,chunkManifest,occurencePlugin]
};
```

Comment: could you please share your webpack config file ?

Comment: @Jose ..Webpack config added..Thanks